# Get # of commits in current branch with bash script

Tags: git, bash

How do I fix this script?

```
var commits() {
  var $GITABRANCH = "git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD"
  "git rev-list --count $GITABRANCH"
}
```

getting parse errors.

Comment: Could you post the exact errors? Also post the `#!` line. And when you say "fix", did it used to work? Or are you looking for debugging help with a non-working script? It doesn't look like bash. It looks an awful lot like Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define as:

```
commits() {
    git rev-list --count ${1-HEAD}
}
```

For `HEAD`, use as:

```
$ commits
19311
```

For any other commit-ish:

```
$ commits 1deac0de
7291
```

Comment: Thank you. So that ${1-Head} is a sequence from commit #1 to HEAD, right? Not $1 as a variable.

Comment: No, that means use the first argument as a commitish value to pass to the git command. If no first argument given, default to HEAD.

Comment: `${1}` means "the first argument", while `-HEAD` means default to the string "HEAD" if the first argument is missing or empty.